# What’s a good client-side fallback for HTML5 form field validation?

Tags: forms, html, cross-browser, validation, modernizr

I've seen many different suggestions for fallbacks for browsers who don't fully implement html5 forms (solutions involving Modernizr, YepNope, Jquery validate...) but I haven't managed to get anything to work effectively.

Essentially apart from adding a datepicker which I've managed to get going with Modernizr and JQuery datepicker all I really need to do is get the validation to work in all browsers (main priority is the email validation)

Chrome and FF everything seems to work natively, yet surprisingly Safari validates without a proper email address. IE obviously doesn't support it either

Could anyone help with a reasonably straightforward fallback (probably via Modernizr)?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried [webshims lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html)? It's build on top of jQuery and I have implemented the forms chapter of HTML5 very accurately. You can find a list of supported attributes, properties and methods on the [webforms site of webhims lib](http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/demos/webforms.html).

I would like to have some feedback on this.

cheers
Alex

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that proper validation should be done **server-side**, you can easily plug one of the many [jQuery validation plugins](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

Comment: Thanks, I do have a basic server side validation, it's just I'm trying to find a way to mimic modern browsers' client-side validation